# Changing a property of a managed object in NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've got a `NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController`, which works with a subclass of a `NSManagedObject` - `Element`.
I receive an object:
`Element *element = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: indexPath];`
I want to change the property of my `element` instance and save it to the database. How can do it?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You can just set a property of the element and then save the managed object context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the attribute on the Element object as you would normally do, and then save the ManagedObjectContext, as you would normally do.
Be sure to cast the object from that array to an Element object to prevent compiler warnings/ errors.

Comment: `objectAtIndexPath:` returns a generic `id`, so there is no need to cast anything in that code line.

Comment: I am assuming that Element is a subclass of NSManagedObject. To set the properties on that object it needs to be cast to an Element *, or does te compiler infer that from the left side of the assignment?